# KDE converts my .webp , .GIF images to .PNG after copying in clipboard

Tags: kde, clipboard, png, gif

Hi whenever I try to copy and paste .webp or .gif files in KDE to Freeoffice or libreoffice they get converted to .Png,
Is this a clipboard problem?

I'm using KDE 5.18.5
Kubuntu 19.10
Libreoffice appimage 6.4.3.2

Comment: Could you detail the procedure you're using, your version of Kubuntu, your version of LibreOffice?

Comment: According to [this](https://wiki.documentfoundation.org/Media_Support/Linux/Image_Tests), `webp` isn't recognized. But I don't know whether that link is current: it's from May 2019.

Comment: @DKBose I've updated the information you want

Comment: I also asked for the exact procedure. I don't understand why do you need to copy/paste. What is the source of the .webp file? For example, use https://www.gstatic.com/webp/gallery/1.webp. How exactly do you proceed?

Comment: I found a .webp file online and pasted it,I'm more interested in .gif file,I recorded it using peek gif tool.

Comment: @DKBose I will save the image first, then open it in kolourpaint and copy it and then paste it in libre or free office, While for the .gif files I just copy paste them from gwenview only but it is not possible for .webp files.